# Error in release package build on Ionic Pro

Tags: ionic-framework

today I started to run into this error when trying to generate the build for launch.

I clarify that I was doing different versions of packaging without problems and now without changes this happens to me and I do not know why.

> :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have
>   changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>   /usr/src/app/platforms/android/src/plugin/google/maps/PluginMarker.java:1149:
>   error: local variable onComplete is accessed from within inner class;
>   needs to be declared final
>           AsyncLoadImage task = new AsyncLoadImage(cordova, webView, options, onComplete);
>                                                                               ^ Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files
>   use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details. 1 error :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
>     Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

From my Mac I can generate the apk with `ionic cordova build android --prod` and it works without problems on my device. What can be happening?

Regards!

Comment: same problem .. have you found a solution ?

Comment: Use cordova-plugin-googlemaps v2.3.11